# SVN Connector installation is broken in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: installation, svn, eclipse

I installed subversive 4.0.5 and when connector installation screen pops up I select **SVN Kit 1.8.14** from the list. All I get after that is a blink of some window and that's it. After I restart my Eclipse it prompts me to install the connector again and after I repeat the steps the problem happens exactly the same way. So I'm stuck.

---

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Are you on Windows?  Which one?

Comment: Same issue here. OS: MacOS Sierra ver 10.12.5. Eclipse Version: Oxygen Release (4.7.0). Java: Oracle Java SE 8 [1.8.0_121]. I have tried re-installing eclipse & switching workspaces, but no luck.

Comment: I have switched to Subclipse 1.10.13 to keep things going. Its not a drop-in replacement, and i had to re-import all my projects. But it works for my setup.

Comment: I'm on Win10 Pro

Comment: How is this question relevant to ServerFault?

Comment: Its about installation of a software on a computer. Definitely not a programming issue. Where would you post it?

Comment: Same issue here: Ubuntu 16.04. Fresh installation, fresh workspace.

Comment: Some people installed it by doing "Install New Software" and use http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/

Comment: The last comment by serge worked for me.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881840/subversive-svn-connector-installation-fails-in-eclipse-oxygen